# Creating a vertical menu with Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to create a vertical menu using Bootstrap 3. The problem is when I do select some option of menu, the background doesn't change color and the link not open and I guess the problem is with attribute data-toggle="pill". When I remove this attribute the link is opened but the color of background doesn't change.

How could I solve this ?

Trying

```
<div class="panel panel-red">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                <li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")" data-toggle="pill" class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"> Home</a></li>
                <li class="active"><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Estado")" class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"> Estados</a></li>
                <li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Condado")" class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"> Condados</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"> Usuários</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some way to change the `active` class. For example, with jQuery...

```
$('.nav-stacked li').click(function(){
    $('.nav-stacked li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

This could also be done on the server-side with .NET by setting class 'active'

https://www.codeply.com/go/GvqxoWYMVU

Here's other examples of Bootstrap vertical menu that may be helpful: https://www.bootply.com/fe4AfcEnKD
https://www.bootply.com/uBoT3zP1P2